# Removing ubuntu from UEFI boot order

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I had Ubuntu 16.04 for some time along side windows 10. I had some problems with Ubuntu and I decided to remove it from my PC. I did all the things including going to Windows repair USB and doing all the stuff there. Except from deleting grub from Ubuntu while it was still on my PC. When I load EasyUEFI, there were 2 options for Ubuntu, I have deleted both of them and after I restarted my PC one was still there. I have done this couple of times by now. It can also be found in UEFI boot order. When I boot into in, it shows something like grub command line with some non important text and that's it. I booted Ubuntu from Live USB and tried efibootmgr, but I get error : EFI variables are not supported on this system. I have included modprobe efivars. Can somebody help me with this situation?

Comment: did you erase /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi from the efi partition? some systems will give a boot entry for any efi boot file it finds in the efi folder.

Comment: @ravery I didn't delete any file or folder within Ubuntu as the guide didn't show any of that, I found that later.

Comment: if you are booting only windows the the efi folder on the efi partition should only have /boot and /windows in it. yes many guides were written for legacy boot and lack extra info for efi boot situations

Comment: Deleting the `EFI/ubuntu` directory on the ESP, as ravery suggests, will *probably* work. There's an extra complication in that Ubuntu, or some other tool or procedure, may have left something in the `/EFI/BOOT` directory, too, and that may be what's re-creating your "zombie" entries (AFAIK, no EFI does active scanning, as ravery claims); but deleting `EFI/ubuntu` is the first step.